# How to rerun my job after it's end?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.Net Library. I wrote some trigger:

```
var t = 
   TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithIdentity("FirstTask", "TaskGroup")
   .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(16, 17, 0))
   .EndAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(17, 17, 0))
   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever()
                             .WithIntervalInSeconds(1))
   .Build();
```

If I exclude `.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)` I have an exception that the retry time can't be zero. So, how can I restart my job when it has finished? Also I didn't find the quartz.net configure file to set maximum threads for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than it looked at first:

```
var job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>().WithIdentity(new JobKey("Task_1", "TaskGroup")).Build();
var t = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("Trigger_1", "TaskGroup")
        .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(21, 15, 0))
        .EndAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(21, 18, 0))
        .Build();
_scheduleService.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, t);
```

And implementing method in listiner:

```
public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
{
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > context.Trigger.EndTimeUtc)
        return;
    context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(context.Trigger.Key, context.Trigger);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To set max thread count to 50:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection { { @"quartz.threadPool.threadCount", @"50" } };
var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

And do not exclude `WithIntervalInSeconds`, Quartz must know, when to run again

Comment: How many treads in quartz by defolt? Yep, but I need to run the job again after it's completed. Not by timer,

Comment: @user3818229 10 (ten) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108403/how-can-i-set-the-number-of-threads-in-the-quartz-net-threadpool

Comment: Thanks! But what about rerunning my task?

Comment: @user3818229 as i said, leave your code as is. It looks ok

Comment: With this interval my task rerunning after 1 second. But it is not what I want to do.

Comment: @user3818229 so, describe what do you want, because Quartz.net is a scheduler and it must have an interval

Comment: I wanna rerun my task without interval. Immediately after the job is done.

Comment: Specifying without a delay. But not during its work.

Comment: @user3818229 well, I don't know your specifics, but I can't imagine, when difference in 1 second is important. Maybe, you need something else instead of Quartz.net

Answer (score 1):

In my previous job we configure `Quartz threadpool` as the following:

```
quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
```

Read more about it in [Configuration](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html) section.

@stuartd provide an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930384/how-do-i-force-a-quartz-net-job-to-restart-intervall-after-completion).
Take his answer and then change the trigger to use `StartNow` method:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                            .startNow()
                            .build();
```

@SchlaWiener also provide a nice solution using `TopShelf`.

Comment: What I really want to achive is to start a job between startTime and endTime and after the completion start again everytime. Also stop theese series if endTime was expire.

Comment: @user3818229 so customize `RepeatAfterCompletionJobListener` to do it. Inject the dates(start, stop and stop expire) and then add the logic...