# Variable interval in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Does anyone know is it possible to schedule a job in Quartz.net with variable interval?
For example, I have an interval 10 to 20 and I need to schedule a job, which would be executed every n seconds, where n is random number between 10 and 20 refreshed after each job execution.

Thanks.

Comment: Where make this sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930384/how-do-i-force-a-quartz-net-job-to-restart-intervall-after-completion

Comment: Can't you just remove the original trigger using the UnschedulerJob method?: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/ff17ee5c-4ba8-34e5-6dfc-600a13a6de2e.htm
...and then add a new trigger with the new interval using the ScheduleJob method: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/84be9956-052d-05d7-4366-0837fcd6d78b.htm

There is also a RescheduleJob method that does both: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/44656a29-199e-7373-5547-e20318780802.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your trigger for first fire in this way:

```
var triggerKey = new TriggerKey("simpleTrigger", "simpleTriggerGroup");
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                    .StartNow()
                    .Build();
```

Then, in the Execute method of your job class modify the trigger:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} hello this is a test", DateTime.Now.ToString("r")));

        var newInterval = new Random().Next(20, 30);

        // retrieve the trigger
        var oldTrigger = context.Scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("simpleTrigger", "simpleTriggerGroup"));

        // obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
        var tb = oldTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder();

        // update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
        var newTrigger = tb.StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(newInterval)).Build();

        context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(oldTrigger.Key, newTrigger);
        Console.WriteLine("Trigger fired... changed interval to {0}", newInterval);
    }
```

The job will be executed in different intervals.

Comment: thanks! I've done it with job listener, but your way works too!